# acts_as_follower for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the acts_as_follower gem. Using example code it is working fine for a User following another User object. But I also want to have a User follow an Article.

The code looks fairly simple except for the fact that the **FollowsController** seems to be coded specifically towards a user object. Should I have separate actions for a create on each type of object?

**controllers/follows_controller.rb**

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
  end
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
...
acts_as_followable
acts_as_follower
...
```

**models/article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  acts_as_followable
  ...
end
```

**views/follows/create.js.erb**

```
$('#follow_user').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "shared/follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user}) %>');
```

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
 ...
 <% if user_signed_in? %>
   <div id="follow_user">
     <%= render :partial => "shared/follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user} %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

**views/articles/index.html.erb**

```
...
<% if current_user.following?(article) %>
    <%= button_to("Un-Follow #{article.id}", article_follow_path(article.to_param, current_user.get_follow(article).id), :method => :delete, :remote => true) %>
<% else %>
    <%= button_to("Follow #{article.id}", article_follows_path(article.to_param), :remote => true) %>
<% end %>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :articles do
  resources :follows, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end

resources :users do
  resources :follows, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FollowsController is your problem.  There are a couple of ways to handle this, one of which is to use a dedicated follows controller for each model that acts as a followable (e.g. FollowsUsersController, FollowsArticlesController, etc.) and use the appropriate controller in your config/routes.rb .  The controllers can all descend from a parent FollowsController that just leaves `followable` as a method to be implemented.

In app/controllers/follows_controller.rb

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    current_user.follow(followable)
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.stop_following(followable)
  end
end
```

In app/controllers/follows_users_controller.rb

```
class FollowsUsersController < FollowsController
  def followable
    @followable ||= User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

In app/controllers/follows_articles_controller.rb

```
class FollowsArticlesController < FollowsController
  def followable
    @followable ||= Article.find(params[:article_id])
  end
end
```

In config/routes.rb

```
resources :articles do
  resources :follows, :controller => 'follows_articles', :only => [:create, :destroy]
end

resources :users do
  resources :follows, :controller => 'follows_users', :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

and you'll need customized JS views for each controller

views/follows_users/create.js.erb

```
$('#follow_user').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "shared/follow_user", :locals => {:user => @followable}) %>');
```

views/follows_articles/create.js.erb

```
$('#follow_article').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "shared/follow_article", :locals => {:article => @followable}) %>');
```